# Удаление строк в таблице со значением 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть таблица, которая с каждым годом автоматически расширяется.

Задача: надо взять все tr из данной таблицы и в каждой строке таблицы взять все td, кроме первого td и второго td (Это значения "Наименование пункта"). После удалить, где значения только нули во всей строке. (значения 0 X Y считается нормой)

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>12 000</td>
    <td>24 000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>12 000</td>
    <td>24 000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>12 000</td>
    <td>24 000</td>
</tr>
```

Пояснение: Удалить строки tr, где все значения 0 0 0, кроме первого td и второго td (значение с 0 0 0 могут оказаться на любой строке);

Пробовал через поиск, что-то не выходит. Через map перебрать массив, тоже не вышло. Подскажите, как можно отследить у таблицы строки, где значения 0 0 0 и удалить их?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var aa = $('#finance-Table tr');
                for (i = 0; i <= aa.length; i++) {
                    var bb = aa[i].find('td:not(:first-child, :nth-child(2))');
                    if (bb.text() == "0 0 0") {
                        aa[i].remove();
                    }
                }
)};
```

Я так понимаю, что метод find находит лишь первый элемент и проблема скорее всего в этом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Вашу задачу (а именно - удаление ячеек со значением "0 0 0"), то решается она элементарно: проходите по всем ячейкам, находите те, где 0 0 0, и удаляете.

В решение я добавил setTimeout для наглядности:

```js
setTimeout( function() {
  $('td').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == '0 0 0') {
      //$(this).remove();
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    }
  });
}, 3000);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>12 000</td>
    <td>24 000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>0 0 0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>12 000</td>
    <td>24 000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0 0 0</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>Наименование пункта</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>12 000</td>
    <td>24 000</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Почти правильно поняли, но требовалось удалить целиком строку (2-ю и 4-ю, если судить по примеру), т.к. там в 3, 4, 5 столбике значения нули. Но я понял что надо перебором через each, спасибо

Comment: @Morner, ну, строку так строку :) поправил ответ

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял из вопроса, автору нужно удалить строку.
В ответе @humster_spb, если удалить только ячейки, то верстка таблицы поедет. Нужно удалить строку, которая содержит эту ячейку.

$(this).closest("tr").remove();

Прошу прощения, исправил имя автора давшего ответ

Comment: ну, если строку, то да - именно так